# spl_autoload_register() Undefined

Tags: php, apache

I am currently moving some php code to my apache server from XAMPP. The spl_autoload_register() function works as expected in XAMPP, but not on my apache server. I keep getting the following error: "Call to undefined function spl_autoload_register() in [file path] [stack trace]." I am currently using PHP version 8.2.7, as per phpinfo(). I can't make heads or tails of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my bootstrap.php which is making the call to the auto load function.

```
<?php
    //App root path
    define('APP_ROOT', 'path');

    //Required files
    require APP_ROOT . 'pathToConfigFile';
    require APP_ROOT . 'pathToFunctionsFile';

    //Set autoload function
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        $path = APP_ROOT . 'pathToClassesFolder';
        require $path . $class . '.php';
    });
?>
```

I wanted to test the bootstrap.php file only in my index file before adding anything else (to make sure my paths were correct). So there are currently no files making any calls to the autoloader, just the bootstrap.php file.

So far, I haven't tried much. I understand that there are a few other autoloading options, but I wanted to stick to spl as I am most familiar with it. Should the solution include another autoload option I would just need to bite the bullet I suppose.

Comment: I agree, this makes no sense. I know that isn't much help, but `spl_autoload_register()` is normally part of the standard PHP installation. So, the question is, is there something special about the installation you're using? Cheap hosting provider perhaps? A custom install?

Answer (score 0):

- Given the message I would imagine that the spl module is either not installed or not enabled, check the extensions directory and the php.ini file respectively. If it is not mentioned there is a pretty good chance that it has not even been installed! Refer to the PHP site for further details on adding and configuring PHP extensions.
  you can see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file) to find php.ini
- There are also a number of other potentially missing php extensions highlighted - the most important of which would be mysqli - make sure that it is installed and/or enabled.
- There are also Apache Modules that have been highlighted and you need to investigate that there are no issues because of these. Refer to the Apache server site for information on configuring the server correctly.
- Whilst you might have the minimum base models of AMP to effect installation, the server is clearly not correctly configured.